# ¿Rutas de express se cruzan?

Tags: nodejs, express

Me ha generado una inquietud al hacer unas pruebas.
Tengo el siguiente manejadore de rutas hijo de /remisión

```
const remisionRouter = Router()
remisionRouter.get("/listado/:nRegistro", remisionMidd.listar(), remisionController.listar);
remisionRouter.get("/:codigoRemision", remisionMidd.cargar(), remisionController.cargar);
export { remisionRouter }
```

Ellas funcionan, la duda es que cuando mando la siguiente request :
`/remision/listado` sin el params `/:nRegistro` ingresa en la segunda ruta
`remisionRouter.get("/:codigoRemision", remisionMidd.cargar(), remisionController.cargar);`

Quiero saber porque ocurre esto.

Comment: ocurre por que la primer regla no se cumple y si se cumple la segunda, proba el parametro como opcional `/:nRegistro?` y luego lo testeas con un `if ( typeof undefined != typeof nRegistro ) {`

Comment: Ok ya entendí amigo, me hiciste caer en cuenta, que cuando no mando el parametro /:nRegistro express toma el segmento /listado como el parámetro de la segunda  `/:codigoRemision`

Comment: otra opción que he visto mucho es agregar un listar todos como primer regla onda `remisionRouter.get("/listado", remisionMidd.listarTodas() ...` dependerá de cómo tengas organizado el code y que sea mas legible/mantenible